# Symfony2 ImageType Form Error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I have one entity like this:

```
class Image
{

/**
 * Identifier
 *
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * Image path
 *
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $path;

/**
 * Image file
 *
 * @var \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
 *
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
protected $file;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

and other entities have for example:

```
class User {
  protected $id;

/**
 * Avatar image
 *
 * @var Image
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vendor\MediaBundle\Entity\Image", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $avatar;
//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

my builder user form Type looks like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('avatar', new ImageType(), array(
            'required' => false,

        ));
```

and the ImageType looks like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('file', 'file', array('required' => false))
        ->add('order', 'hidden');
```

When I'm not uploading any file I'm receiving this error:

> This form should not contain extra fields.

and the parameter is "file"

is driving me crazy...

Comment: At the moment I fixed this problem removing $form->isValid() from the controller... disgusting patch but works...
Any better idea?

Comment: {{form_row(form.avatar)}} print order field and file input.
And the parameters that contains the extra fields is "file" not order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are using Symfony2.3, there was a bug in [this commit](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/a2b15359d81563d52b62b4357407efa949a0706a#L0L539).

[Fix](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/de1915f40506fc86a8b5f2ca0af3478044ddf58b) has been commited an hour ago.

Update symfony using composer :

```
./compser.phar update symfony/symfony
```

Hope this helps